# Target a dynamically rendered ListView component with refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Teaching myself react native by making a chat app, now when someone clicks on a delete button next to the message (not visible in this code as it's irrelevant), it deletes it from the database but I need to make the changes here in the app.

For this I have set a ref one each of the `<Message/>` components and I have the ref which matches the ref on the component. But i need to target the actual component node which has that ref.

Is refs the way to go about doing this? If not, what else can I do?

Many thanks

edit: Full code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { ListView, View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableHighlight } from "react-native"
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import { Hideo } from 'react-native-textinput-effects';

import Message from './Message'

export default class Chat extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.onSend = this.onSend.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      messages: this.ds.cloneWithRows([]),
      messageContent: '',
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    // Get all of the messages from firebase database and push them into "nodes" array which then gets set in the "messages" state above in handleChat.
    const chatRef = firebase.database().ref().child('general');
    this.messages = [];
    chatRef.on('child_added', snap => {
      this.messages.push({user: snap.val().user.name,
          text: snap.val().text,
          messageId: snap.key
        })
        this.handleChat(this.messages);
      }
    ).bind(this);
    // this is what happens when someone removes a comment
    chatRef.on('child_removed', snap => {
      const messageId = snap.key; // <- This is the key in the database, for example: '-KVZ_zdbJ0HMNz6lEff'
      this.removeMessage(messageId);
    })
  }
  removeMessage(messageId){
      let messages = this.messages.filter(message => message.messageId !== messageId);
      this.handleChat(messages);
  }
  handleChat(messages) {
    this.setState({messages: this.ds.cloneWithRows(messages)})
  }
  onSend(messages) {
    const generalRef = firebase.database().ref().child('general');
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    generalRef.push(
      {
        _id: 1,
        text: this.state.messageContent,
        createdAt: new Date().getTime(),
        user: {
          _id: 2,
          name: user.displayName,
          avatar: 'http://mdepinet.org/wp-content/uploads/person-placeholder.jpg'
        }
      });
    this.setState({messageContent: ''})
  }
  removeMessage(messageId){
    let messages = this.messages.filter(message => message.messageId !== messageId);
    this.handleChat(messages);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
        <ListView
        style={{ marginBottom: 60 }}
        enableEmptySections={true}
        dataSource={this.state.messages}
        renderRow={message => <Message name={message.user} text={message.text}/> }/>

      <Hideo
        style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0}}
        onChangeText={messageContent => this.setState({messageContent})} value={this.state.messageContent}        placeholder="Name"
        iconClass={Icon}
        iconName={'envelope'}
        iconColor={'white'}
        iconBackgroundColor={'#222'}
        inputStyle={{ color: '#464949' }}
      />
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onSend} style={{position: 'absolute', alignItems: 'center',   bottom: 10, right: 10, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: '#d4af37'}}>
      <Text style={{color: 'whitesmoke', fontSize: 20, padding: 5}}>Send</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  username: {
    fontFamily: 'AvenirNext-Bold'
  },
  comment: {
    fontFamily: 'AvenirNext-Regular'
  },
  bubble: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 250,
    backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
    margin: 15,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 20
  }
})
```

Comment: `renderRow` should be passed into `map` method of your messages array, so deleting message from array will be enough to remove it from messages list as well.

Comment: Which map method?

Comment: `messages.map(message => this.props.renderRow(message))`

Comment: Just remove message you want to delete from `this.state.messages` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using refs to ListView row items is not a Good idea. As Elmeister told we just need to remove the message elements from array and update the ListView datasource in order to delete a message from ListView.

Here is a sample code which will give you an idea of how you can do the same in your app.

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';


class StackOverflow extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.messages = this.getMessages();
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.messages)
    };
  }


  getMessages() {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      arr.push({
        user: 'User ' + i,
        text: 'This is a sample user message ' + i,
        messageId: 'messageId' + i,
      });
    }
    return arr;
  }

  onDeletePress(messageId) {
    this.messages = this.messages.filter(message => message.messageId !== messageId);
    this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.messages)
    });
  }

  renderRow(rowData) {
    return (
      <View style={{padding:8}}>
        <Text>{rowData.user}</Text>
        <Text>{rowData.text}</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={{alignSelf :'flex-end',backgroundColor:'red'}}
          onPress={this.onDeletePress.bind(this,rowData.messageId)}>
          <Text>Delete</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 22}}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('StackOverflow', () => StackOverflow);
```

In the above example, We are creating dummy messages and saving them in `messages` array and updating `dataSource` with messages.

When `onDeletePress` is called we pass the `messageId` to that method, and below line

`this.messages = this.messages.filter(message => message.messageId !== messageId);`
removes the message from `messages` array. Then we update the `dataSource` state which will update the ListView.

In your code probably these changes you will have to make,

Change `handleChat`

```
handleChat(messages) {
    this.setState({messages: this.ds.cloneWithRows(messages)})
}
```

Update Chat component like below,

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import {ListView, View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableHighlight} from "react-native"
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import {Hideo} from 'react-native-textinput-effects';

import Message from './Message'

export default class Chat extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.chatRef = firebase.database().ref().child('general');
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.onSend = this.onSend.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      messages: this.ds.cloneWithRows([]),
      messageContent: '',
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // Get all of the messages from firebase database and push them into "nodes" array which then gets set in the "messages" state above in updateMessageList.
    this._messages = [];
    this.chatRef.on('child_added', snap => {
        this._messages.push({
          user: snap.val().user.name,
          text: snap.val().text,
          messageId: snap.key
        });
        this.updateMessageList(this._messages);
      }
    ).bind(this);
    // this is what happens when someone removes a comment
    this.chatRef.on('child_removed', snap => {
      const messageId = snap.key; // <- This is the key in the database, for example: '-KVZ_zdbJ0HMNz6lEff'
      this.removeMessage(messageId);
    }).bind(this);
  }

  removeMessage(messageId) {
    this._messages = this._messages.filter(message => message.messageId !== messageId);
    this.updateMessageList(this._messages);
  }

  updateMessageList(messages) {
    this.setState({messages: this.ds.cloneWithRows(messages)})
  }

  onSend(messages) {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.chatRef.push(
      {
        _id: 1,
        text: this.state.messageContent,
        createdAt: new Date().getTime(),
        user: {
          _id: 2,
          name: user.displayName,
          avatar: 'http://mdepinet.org/wp-content/uploads/person-placeholder.jpg'
        }
      });
    this.setState({messageContent: ''})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
        <ListView
          style={{ marginBottom: 60 }}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          dataSource={this.state.messages}
          renderRow={message => <Message name={message.user} text={message.text}/> }/>

        <Hideo
          style={{position: 'absolute', bottom: 0}}
          onChangeText={messageContent => this.setState({messageContent})} value={this.state.messageContent}
          placeholder="Name"
          iconClass={Icon}
          iconName={'envelope'}
          iconColor={'white'}
          iconBackgroundColor={'#222'}
          inputStyle={{ color: '#464949' }}
        />
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onSend}
                            style={{position: 'absolute', alignItems: 'center',   bottom: 10, right: 10, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: '#d4af37'}}>
          <Text style={{color: 'whitesmoke', fontSize: 20, padding: 5}}>Send</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  username: {
    fontFamily: 'AvenirNext-Bold'
  },
  comment: {
    fontFamily: 'AvenirNext-Regular'
  },
  bubble: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 250,
    backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5',
    margin: 15,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 20
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the very detailed answer. Following your instructions I have managed get the message to delete live, but when a new message appears the deleted message reappears before the new message. The delete only happens when i manually go back and then back into chat to remount the component. And the message is correctly deleting in the database so it must be getting stuck somewhere on the react native side. Do you have any idea where this bug is happening?

Comment: @Apswak I have updated the answer. Please check if this resolves the issue.

Comment: If not please update your question with the code of how you get all the messages first and populate the list

Comment: I have updated the message so you have the full code and it's more clear. the only thing you don't have is the individual <Message/> component but you can imagine that being just a bubble which displays the name and the text. I'm getting the messages from my firebase database with the `    const chatRef = firebase.database().ref().child('general');` line

Comment: with that line i'm connecting to the database, specifically my "general" storage where all the messages are stored, and the code following that loops through and pushes all the messages into "nodes" which then gets set in the state.

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue or some new error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127494/discussion-between-jickson-and-apswak).